# Cloudflare infinte loop (Checking if the site connection is secure)

Tags: security, tor, cloudflare, tails

What can I do to fix the CloudFlare "Checking if the site connection is secure" infinite loop?

I'm tying to load a website. The very first GET gets sent to an interstitial page run by Cloudflare that says

> Checking if the site connection is secure
>
> [site] needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.

When the page first loads:

1. first a spinning circle appears
2. then the circle disappears
3. then a reCAPTCHA-like grey table with a "challenge spinner" appears, but all it says is `Verifying...` with a green spinner. It stays like this for a *long* time, leaving me to twiddle my thumbs in frustration.
4. then, finally, the "challenge spinner" disappears and another grey spinning circle appears
5. then the page reloads completely, this time with a "challenge spinner" with a checkbox that says `Verify you are human`.
6. I click the checkbox, and it changes back to the green spinner.
7. Then the challenge spinner disappears
8. Then a grey spinner appears
9. Then the page reloads and I'm again presented with another "challenge spinner" that says `Verify you are human`.
10. GOTO 6

I'm trying to access a website in TAILS (using Tor Browser, for security reasons). This issue occurs on a fresh boot. It should go without saying that I'm not doing anything malicious, but I'll say it: **all I've done is type the naked domain into the address bar and press `<enter>`**.

Is this a bug? I've done this infinite loop for half an hour. How can I prove to CloudFlare that I'm human and escape this infinite loop?

Comment: Have you had the problem in the past? Have you used Tails on this site before? Does it work without Tails?

Comment: @schroeder I think this question should be answered for "the general site" using CloudFlare (focusing on CloudFlare, not the specific site that it's fronting) for the benefit of other readers, but I did not have this issue on this specific site when visiting it in TAILS in the past. This is especially a problem because I created an account, put money on it, and now I can no longer access my account. Again, let's focus on CloudFlare here -- this issue happens on a *lot* of different sites.

Comment: But it ***does*** matter how you access Cloudflare. Is this a problem if you don't use Tails? This might not be a CF issue but a Tails issue ... If Tails is changing things during CF's test, then you might get a loop.

Comment: Tor browser effectively hides your machine location by layers of redirection (The Onion Router = layers). The site you're trying to reach demands a more direct connection. See https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15108/tor-browser-and-amazon-com

Comment: See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93923/is-it-legal-for-a-business-to-deny-me-access-to-their-store-on-the-basis-of-how

Comment: See also https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/23778/31208

Comment: The question belongs on the [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It might not be possible.

Unlike offline spaces, **it's currently legal for a business to discriminate against you** purely on the basis of *how you look* by denying you access to their online premises.

Unfortunately, the methods used by CloudFlare (a private for-profit company) to deny customers access to a business' website use closed-source algorithms that are not (yet) legally required to be disclosed to the public for the purposes of transparency (to ensure that they do not violate the law due to unlawful discrimination).

It's highly likely that these fingerprinting algorithms (which are notorious for false-positives leading to widespread discrimination on the Internet) are using machine-learning algorithms. Fortunately, in 2023 the EU has begun to draft legislation that will require disclosure, public review, and restrictions of AI-powered algorithms. US lawmakers have also met with leading experts on AI algorithms to discuss regulations.

#### Lobby the government

Hopefully one day we will have data privacy laws that protect consumers from businesses that discriminate on the basis of how you look (and, rather, only enforce protections on the basis of *how you act*), but currently the best solution to this problem is: **write to your legislators and donate to digital-rights NGO lobbyists like the EFF, Open Rights Group, Privacy International, etc**.

#### Lobby the business

You can also contact the business and let them know that their Cloudflare setup is misconfigured and causing false-positives (CC their security team).

At the time of writing, Cloudflare's default settings *do not* result in an infinite loop. In fact, if you go to Cloudflare's website and try to login as a customer, you probably won't get stuck in an infinite loop. Cloudflare knows how to configure & test their own systems not to break like this; many of their customers don't.

Cloudflare's customers can easily enable "anti-bot protection" in cloudflare and misconfigure it to the point to where their users experience false-positive issues like this questions describes. This is, in fact, a misconfiguration. It probably wasn't detected by the business due to poor testing.

**Email them**. Let them know that you can't access their website. Tell their security team that their cloudflare setup is misconfigured, and **ask them to test their website on Tor Browser**.

Answer (score -2):

### On the internet, nobody knows how you look

The internet relies on [a whole suite of protocols that work together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). Just to name two, the TCP/IP dictates that you need an IP to get an answer at all, and HTTPS tells the port as well as how to encrypt the data between you and the server.

Now, the capcha service knows exactly one solid thing about you: Your IP. And now, let's look at TOR browsers in the equitation:

On the most basic level, TOR browsers route their traffic from your computer to a special server, where the request is stored for a moment as that server does the same request to the actual server you want to talk to, but using that special server's IP as "sender". And here things begin to unravel:

- A lot of captcha services check the IP of the sender against a list of known, bad IPs, that are used often by malicious people. That list includes the known part of the TOR network.
- TOR nodes share IP addresses between **many** users. If Bob and Alice both use the same node, Bob's and Alice's answers to the captcha are treated the same on the captcha side, resulting in the service recognizing it as failed or non-human activity. In fact, this can roll back to the point above: this is how IPs get blacklisted.
- TOR nodes take time to do stuff. This can lead to timeouts on the captcha service side and thus rejection of the answers.
- TOR's setup **requires** to have the TOR node act as a "Man in the middle" on your communication with any server. This can result in encryption failures on HTTPS, resulting in server side rejection of messages.

This is not an exhaustive list of reasons the captcha answer is rejected, but just a glimpse under the hood of the *technical* side.
To evade the loop of answers or connections being rejected, you might need to go without TOR so you can comply with the technical limitations. It might be possible to run through a different TOR node or VPN and get a connection that way, but you still might be experiencing problems with connection timeouts.

### On the legal side...

[On the legal side, this was asked on Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93923/10334) - and to paraphrase: it's a thing of "no shirt, no shoes, no service." Or rephrased for the Internet: "We don't serve TOR users". It is upon the website to set up its ToS in a way that does not discriminate based on **protected characteristics** - and using TOR is not a protected characteristic, thus throwing us back to the technical side: they are allowed to block known TOR IPs and thus do.